# count instances of occurrence of word from paragraphs of text in another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I want to count how many times the name/keyword has been used in a text

```
Page    Contain check
Page 1  sfdsd
Page 2  This is Service 1 and Service 2
Page 3  sfdsd
Page 4  fsdf
Page 5  This is Service 1 
Page 6  Service 2 is on sale
Page 7  sdf
Page 8  Service 2 is good
```

I tried using countif formula =countif(A:A,F:F) but it didnt give results

```
=countif(A:A,F:F)
```

Expected result is as followx

```
Names      Expected Result
Service 1   2
Service 2   3
Service 3   0
```

"Name can be counted twice in one cell.

```
e.g. 'Service 1' is featured, please check more features of 'Service1' below"
```

hence in this case Service 1 is counted 2 times

Comment: Can a substring occur more than once in one cell, and if so, would you need to count them seperately?

Comment: yes it can and that should be counted as well. e.g. " 'Service 1' is featured, please check more features of 'Service1' below" hence in this case Service 1 is counted 2 times

Comment: One more question, did you think about substrings that can mean something different, e.g: If you are looking for `America` in a string `This is an American`, or `Hello World` in `Hello WorldWideWeb`? In other words, what are the odds that your substrings are part of a larger substring that you are not interested in? A clearer example: `Service 1` will also be found in `Service 10` for example

Comment: Good point. I think you would be looking at a VBA solution with either Regex or split to avoid that issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have the following named range:

- **Contain_check** being the list of the strings that contain the names

Presume the names are listed in range `A2:A4`, you can use the following formula in cell `B2` to count the occurrence of the name and drag it down to apply across:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(Contain_check)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Contain_check,A2,"")))/LEN(A2)
```

Replace `A2` to suit your case.

[image: Demo]

> The logic is to use **SUBSTITUTE** function to remove the target name from the strings, use **LEN** function to compare the string length before and after removing the target name, divide the difference by the length of the name will give you the "count" of the target name from each string, and lastly use **SUMPRODUCT** function to add up the counts.

*Please note, in your example `'Service 1' is featured, please check more features of 'Service1' below"`, `Service 1` has a space in between while `Service1` has no space in between so technically they are two different name and it will only return one count for each of them but not `2`. Please clarify if you want to treat `Service 1` and `Service1` as the same name?

Comment: Upvoted :), but still having a concern that made me wait answering myself. As per my comment under OP's question

Comment: @JvdV just saw your comment and this is a very common concern for this type of question and I agree in that case my solution will not return the correct count.

Comment: This works, but as @Terry mentioned, if for works like `Service1` and `Service10` it will still count. and for your question about `Service 1` and `Service1` those should be different

Comment: also, its not can it be not case senstive? i tried to put lower() but its not working

Comment: @user3415869 what would be the maximum number after `Service`? Apart from `'Service 1'`, is there any other possible special symbols in front and/or after the name such as `Service 1?` or `:Service 1`? How did you use the **lower** function (are you able to share your formula)?